# asp.net mvc 3: Page.User.IsInRole("xy") returns null

Tags: authentication, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

I migrated an mvc 2 app to version 3.

Unfortunatly in my partial logon file, an exception is thrown when the user is logged in. The Request.IsAuthenticated returns true, but the Page.User returns null!

And of course

`Page.User.IsInRole("xy")`

throws an exception:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

How do I check the user role with Razor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the solutions by looking at a default mvc3 project:

```
Context.User.IsInRole("xy")
```

instead of Page.User.IsInRole("xy")

Comment: In Razor, You can use `User.IsInRole("xy")` directly.